# JS calculator not working. Operators are not functioning. Every time I run the calc, it only adds

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, function, if-statement

I am very new to JavaScript. I have been trying to figure this out but nothing seems to work. operators seem to be not stable. for example if i subtract 6-6, it'd still give me 12, i.e operators only add in all situations.

```
inp1 = prompt("Enter in a number");
inp1 = Number.parseInt(inp1);
let js1 = inp1;


op = prompt("Enter an operator");
op = ["+", "-", "*", "/"];

inp2 = prompt("Enter another number");
inp2 = Number.parseInt(inp2);
let js2 = inp2;

function addition(x, y) {
    return (x + y);
}
function subtraction(x, y) {
    return (x - y);
}
function multiplication(x, y) {
    return (x * y);
}
function division(x, y) {
    return (x / y);
}

if (op = "+") {
    console.log(addition(js1, js1));

}
else if (op = "-") {
    console.log(subtraction(js1, js2));
}
else if (op = "*") {
    console.log(multiplication(js1, js2));
}
else if (op = "/") {
    console.log(division(js1, js2));
}
else {
    console.log("Sorry! An Error has occurred");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The first problem is in

```
op = ["+", "-", "*", "/"];
```

so after your get the operator from a user, you assign it to a new value

and also

```
if (op = "+") {}
else if (op = "-"){}
```

this is the assignment operator, not the comparator. Instead use:

```
if (op === "+")
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not comparing them in the if statement, instead you are assigning. What you're looking for is this:

```
if(op === "+") {
   //add
} else if(op === "-") {
   //subtract
}
```

You should also look into JavaScripts different ways of comparing https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness